# Microsoft Dynamics CRM Organization Naming

Tags: dynamics-crm-2015

We have 3 environments: dev, test and prod.
All 3 have different servers for web and sql. (6 servers)
We also have 1 AD FS server shared.
MSDCRM 2015 On-Premise (not hosted in cloud).
We have AD with a different OU for each environment.
We plan on integrating with crm api/sdk to get/set data from our accounting software and website.

The thing I am trying to understand is how to name the organization properly.
We want our URL's to be:  (example as orgname="orga")

- crm.company.com/orga
- crm-test.company.com/orga
- crm-dev.company.com/orga

According to our CRM Partner the organization must be unique to its environment. They were trying to suggest we use "crm-dev" as our org name for example in dev, and in test our org would be "crm-test" and in prod "crm" but to me that is not best practice sounding and only the servername should be different in the 3 environments and the orgname would be the same in all 3.

Common sense was telling me that an "organization" would be our company/corporation, and we might actually have other companies too... so lets say for example we had 3 orgs, one called orgA and another orgB. Then our urls would be:

- crm.company.com/orga
- crm.company.com/orgb
- crm-test.company.com/orga
- crm-test.company.com/orgb
- crm-dev.company.com/orga
- crm-dev.company.com/orgb

In all my experience with multi-environments I would think that any differences beyond the "subdomain" or server name would be bad practice but our partner is saying that we have no choice and this IS the best practice that "Microsoft Suggests too"... they say that having the same org name in multiple environments "breaks things." She also said that using our own DNS A Host records to change what URL people would use would also cause issues.

I spent hours searching the web for others asking this question but it seems I'm the only one somehow. I would think it was a popular debate since it is the top-levl of your crm information and affects the URL.

Comment: you can have the same organization name in 3 different servers, I don't see the problem to have different organization names

Comment: If having them named differently doesn't affect things poorly such as using the api or web services when integrating with other systems mainly is part of my concern. I'm wanting to avoid having to start over (or majorly tweak) weeks into the integration after figuring out differently named orgs causes us to have to lookup orgnames per environment etc... when they could have been set the same. The contractors we hired to set it up says that naming them the same causes problems wouldn't divulge any specifics and I am thinking why this be a problem?

Comment: Agree with Guido, I don't see any problem with using the same Organization name in each of the 3 environments - that's how it's usually done.

Answer (score 1):

We are in the same situation as you are, with 3 different CRM2015 on premise-environments (for developers, acceptance testing and production). We use the same organization name (in this case, the name of the company) in all three environments.

We use the server alias to differ between the installations. So, given that the we have named our CRM-based product XYZ and the company is called ABC, we would have the following addresses to the environments:

- XYZ-dev.company.com/ABC at server 1 (dev env)
- XYZ-tst.company.com/ABC at server 2 (test env)
- XYZ.company.com/ABC at server 3 (prod env)

This works fine for us and we haven't had any experience of things breaking because of this.